# SQL search query where the product name

Tags: php, mysql, laravel-8, e-commerce

Here the sample product name "SRM - DAZA RS3 TTRS GTX35 Turbo"

sql like query i'm using this

```
        ->where(function ($q) use ($query) {
        foreach (explode(' ', trim($query)) as $word) {
            $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $word . '%')
                ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $word . '%')
                ->orWhere('tags', 'like', '%' . $word . '%')
                ->orWhereHas('product_translations', function ($q) use ($word) {
                    $q->where('name', 'like', '%' . $word . '%')
                    ->orWhere('description', 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
                })
                ->orWhereHas('stocks', function ($q) use ($word) {
                    $q->where('sku', 'like', '%' . $word . '%');
                });
        }
    })
```

this works perfect but still have an issue. if i search "SRM" im getting this specific product

but if i type mix match word "SRM turbo" im not getting this product.

so please let me know what is the right query that i need to use

Comment: is your collation case sensitive= have you tried  "SRM Turbo" for example

Comment: hi no issue with case sensitive, as i need how ever user search this product should come for and example "SRM Turbo" , "srm turbo" , " daza turbo" , " daza turbo gtx" right now it works one word and continues word. but i need mix match word

Comment: if you change $q->where to $q->orwhere  you will get your rows and more

Comment: No this not solving this issue

Comment: see with ->toSql() the raw output of the query and post it, may then it will get clearer